# Blender 2.83 and 2.90.1 wrong file permissions on MacOS prevent installation for all users

Tags: installation, osx

When Blender 2.83 or 2.90.1 are installed on MacOS Catalina (10.15.7) the folder `/Applications/Blender.app` gets the inappropriate permissions that make it readable only for the user that installed the application. The problem happens with direct installation through the downloaded DMG file or via Homebrew (which just downloads the file for you).

This makes Blender unusable for all other users.

The problem seems to have persisted at least since 2017, see [this related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80027/how-to-install-blender-on-a-mac-so-that-multiple-user-accounts-have-access-to-it), so this makes me think it is not a bug but a "feature", alebeit a very stupid one.

One can fix the permissions with something like this from the command-line

```
sudo find /Applications/Blender.app -type d -exec chmod a+rx {} \;
sudo find /Applications/Blender.app -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;
sudo chmod a+x `find /Applications/Blender.app -perm +100 -type f`
```

but it is a bit stupid that I have to do this. Is there a good reason for this? I am unable to find any information about this, can someone help out?

Comment: I believe you're encountering this bug: https://developer.blender.org/T72605 (don't just read the description, but the second comment by the user who opened it). It's still open and apparently not prioritized. I suggest you add your experience there.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a description with more information, let's hope someone takes care of this.